# Compiling mcrypt on OSX 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: mac-osx

I'm trying to compile mcrypt-2.6.8 on OSX 10.6

```
./configure --with-prefix=/opt/local/mcrypt
...
configure: error: "You need at least libmhash 0.8.15 to compile this program. http://mhash.sf.net/"
```

I have successfully compiled mhash. It's located on /opt/local/mhash. Unfortunately the linker doesn't seem to find the libraries.

I already tried with exporting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, setting CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -L/opt/local/mhash", copying the lib files to /usr/local/lib, ...

**UPDATE:** ./configure works now with

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/opt/local/mhash/include -L/opt/local/mhash/lib"
```

But now "make" fails with

```
../config.h:219:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
rfc2440.c:26:20: error: malloc.h: No such file or directory
rfc2440.c: In function 'dek_load':
rfc2440.c:562: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 5 of 'mhash_keygen_ext' differ in signedness
rfc2440.c: In function 'dek_create':
rfc2440.c:613: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 5 of 'mhash_keygen_ext' differ in signedness
rfc2440.c: In function 'symkey_enc_decode':
rfc2440.c:631: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'header_decode' differ in signedness
rfc2440.c:631: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 3 of 'header_decode' differ in signedness
rfc2440.c:631: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 4 of 'header_decode' differ in signedness
make[2]: *** [rfc2440.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea out there?

Answer (score 4):

I found that I was able to get this working by changing the rfc2440.c source itself. Since my malloc.h file was located in `/usr/include/malloc/malloc.h`, I changed the line from `#include < malloc.h>` to `#include < malloc/malloc.h>` and compiled. There were no compiler errors, and it installed fine with `make install` afterward (technically, `sudo make install`).

Answer (score 2):

[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) does have mcrypt available, and I just confirmed that it compiles fine.  I always prefer that or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) to doing it myself because it's as simple as `port install mcrypt` (when things are working).

Answer (score 1):

If your make fails with this line:

```
rfc2440.c:26:20: error: malloc.h: No such file or directory
```

Then:

```
touch malloc.h;
```

In your build directory before running configure, make.

Answer (score 0):

Often the configure script looks for headers rather than libraries, and libraries are generally located in the $PREFIX/lib directory. Try something like `CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/mhash/include -L/opt/local/mhash/lib" ./configure --with-prefix=/opt/local/mcrypt && make`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally didn't need mcrypt but only libmcrypt. Worked with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `mcrypt`. Later on I installed `mcrypt` using `brew` (package manager for OS X). Made everything simpler and easier.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on how it made things easier? Just a thought.

Comment: Well, because brew does everything automatically. Configuration, Make and Install. Even if a required package is missing brew will install the missing package. After the installation you just have to add mcrypt extension to php.ini. So basically you have only 2 steps.

Step 1: brew install mcrypt-php54
Step 2: add mcrypt extension to php.ini